# How to extract "key" values from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have an object that returns the following using `id *value = [arg1 valueForKey:@"value"];`:

```
value = {
   "item_id" = 1234;
   "item_type" = text;
   turn = 4;
}
```

I used `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([value class]))` to return the object type which is `__NCSFDictionary`.

I want the value of turn in value, so I used:

```
id *turn = [value valueForKey:@"turn"];
```

but it's returning nil.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "id *" probably doesn't compile and certainly isn't what you mean.  Can you paste actual code?

Comment: i can't figure out what you want... id* doesn't work

Comment: you don't need `id *`, you need `id` only.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to do `id turn` not `id *turn`. id is a pointer already.
2. In order to retrieve an object from a dictionary you use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`. The latter is about key value coding. You don't seem to need it here

Comment: This isn't quite right.  NSDictionary will respond to both valueForKey (as does any object) and objectForKey.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/1410210-valueforkey?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
id turn = [value objectForKey:@"turn"];
```